# Custom video banner in homepage in Magento 2.2

Tags: magento2.2

How do I create a custom video banner on the homepage in Magento 2.2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `<iframe>` to upload video anywhere

below code will work anywhere.

```
<iframe width="500" height="300" src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5fzb-qLL2wo" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

you can play a video in banner section by a GIF.
i've also done this many times before. its so easy just replace the image by gif.